# What is the replacement for distutils.util.get_platform()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, distutils

Apparently, Python 3.10 / 3.12 is going to deprecate / remove distutils ([cpython/issues/92584](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92584)).

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a replacement for the one and only function I am using from it; `distutils.util.get_platform()`. What is the replacement for this?

Note that `platform` is **NOT** an answer. I need a function that returns the complete string that is used when building a binary wheel¹, e.g. `macosx-12-x86_64`. Note particularly that there appears to be platform-specific logic embedded in this (e.g. the only other way I know to get the macos version is with a macos-specific API).

(¹ As noted in a comment, `distutils.util.get_platform()` is, strictly speaking, not that function. However, [PEP 425](https://peps.python.org/pep-0425/) specifies that "the platform tag is simply `distutils.util.get_platform()` with all hyphens `-` and periods `.` replaced with underscore `_`." Ergo, it is straight-forward and platform-agnostic to derive the tag from `distutils.util.get_platform()`. An acceptable answer may therefore give an approved, public API which produces the platform tag directly, *or* a compatible replacement for `distutils.util.get_platform()`.)

Comment: Well, based on [this discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-425-platform-tag/5157), it seems that perhaps no one knows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your use-case, [`sysconfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig.get_platform) has a replacement

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_platform()
```

This is what the wheel project itself used as a replacement for `distutils.util.get_platform()` when removing distutils from the code in [*Replaced all uses of distutils with setuptools #428*](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/pull/428).

Comment: Is that guaranteed to give the same result (at least on macOS)? [This discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-425-platform-tag/5157) didn't seem to imply that it does?

Comment: @Matthew under the hood, the code of ``sysconfig.get_platform`` and ``distutils.util.get_host_platform`` is 99% identical. For windows, distutils additionally checks ``os.environ.get('VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH')``. So strictly speaking, it's currently not guaranteed to give the exact same result, but it's the next best thing.

Comment: @Matthew Your question title and your question body ask two different things, or maybe you were using an incorrect function in the first place - the exact replacement for the bdist_wheel tags would be `from wheel.bdist_wheel import get_platform`, which does some further modification on the result of sysconfig / distutils.util function. However, wheel has no public API (as clearly stated in their README) so you'd probably have to replicate their modifications manually if you want an exact replacement.

Comment: Good point. I added wording to explain the discrepancy and why your answer is acceptable in spite of such.

Comment: On that note, it turns out `distutils.util.get_platform`/`sysconfig.get_platform` does indeed not match the actual tag used in the wheel. So much for PEP 425 .

Comment: This PEP is almost 10 years old now, so not too surprising if things have moved a bit since then and it's in need of an update..